# Add a reset button to the options page (using Settings API)?

Tags: plugin-development, reset

How do I add a reset button using the Settings API?

I use

add_settings_field

To add a field...is there a hook to add a reset button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this Q some couple of month myself. You don't need a hook or anything like that. Just remove the options you added to the DB, then add your defaults.

If you need just the button function: `submit_button()`;