# Is there a reset_button()?

Tags: forms

After [5 years](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27377/add-a-reset-button-to-the-options-page-using-settings-api/27382#27382), is there a `reset_button()`?

If not (yet) there is, in WordPress what is the **best** way for the cleaning of a backend form fields?

Comment: [Reset buttons are a usability sin](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/reset-and-cancel-buttons/). Try to find a better way to achieve what your users need.

Comment: @toscho, thanks, You are right: that reset button is (only) for me, in a back-end form with many option fields (that I must reset periodically for test and some other reasons) :-) P.S.: in back-end, *pure* `<input type=reset>` doesn't work.

Comment: @toscho, lol just a month ago a client asked me to implement a reset and a week ago he asked for an undo. guess that some basic truths never die

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the submit button code:

```
print str_replace( 
    '"submit"', 
    '"reset"', 
    get_submit_button( 'Reset' ) 
);
```

This should create a button with the regular style for submit buttons. The attributes `name`, `type` and `id` will be set to `reset`. Not tested. :)